# ifc.js hiding example: hover highlights elements in non-displayed subsets

Tags: ifc

The issue is with the Hiding example (subset example with checkboxes):
helloworld/main/examples/web-ifc-viewer/hiding/bundle.js

When a subset is not-displayed, hover still highlights the element in the non-displayed subset. The solution as proposed on Discord was to remove the subset model from the array: ifcviewer.context.items.pickableIfcModels,

but it's not clear to me how or where to do this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

most probably because " ifcviewer.context.items.pickableIfcModels" is still thinks that you're dealing with the model as a whole not with the subsets,

you need to add this function:

```
function togglePickable(mesh, isPickable)
    pickable = viewer.context.items.pickableIfcModels
if(isPickable) {
pickable.push(mesh)
} else {
const index = pickable.indexof(mesh)
pickable.splice(index, 1)
}
```

and on setupCheckbox function add this line under

```
if(checkbox.checked){
..
togglePickable(subset, true)
}else{
...
togglePickable(subset, false)
}
```

and on setupCategory function add the following:

```
togglePickable(subset[category], true)
```

and on your load model function you also need to add:

```
togglePickable("your model", true)
```

and it shall work ^^